# CXF TransformOutInterceptor removing SOAP attachments when used

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, cxf

I have a SOAP client and I need to set the default namespace - which I am doing with a TransformOutInterceptor as such:

```
Map<String, String> outTransformMap = Collections.singletonMap("Test", "Test"); 
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.transform.TransformOutInterceptor transformOutInterceptor = new org.apache.cxf.interceptor.transform.TransformOutInterceptor(); 
transformOutInterceptor.setDefaultNamespace("http://test"); 
transformOutInterceptor.setOutTransformElements(outTransformMap); 
ClientProxy.getClient(client).getEndpoint().getOutInterceptors().add(transformOutInterceptor);
```

This is working fine in terms of changing the default namespace, and the SOAP message is being successfully received and parsed by the server, however, by running the transformation it is removing all the SOAP attachments and changing the Content Type of the message from `mime` to `text/xml`.

Can anyone help? Is this a bug or am I missing something?  I've tried changing the phases at which the interceptor is run, but with to avail.

Many thanks

Matt